# Excel Remove Row's With Multiple Values

Tags: excel, multiple-columns

I would like to remove every row, which contain like (AA12, AA43, AA46).

I have about 5k lines and 800 values(AA12), so remove every single one with filtering is not the optimal solution.

Thanks for responses!

Comment: Delete the entire column?

Comment: Use the Len function to calculate the length of the cell content, if it contains multiple values the length will be longer then when it contains only one value. If you put that in an IF statement you could output 1's when multiple values and 0's when only one value. And then delete all the 1's

Comment: Yes, i need to delete the entire Row

Comment: @MarcHofstetter delete entire row if it contains the values AA12, AA43, AA46 in any of the cells?

Comment: I will describe you. I've a list with many words (5k). I have another list with around 1k words. I need find all the 1k words in the 5k excel sheet and after that, i have to remove the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below formula for conditional formatting,

```
=OR(COUNTIF(Sheet3!$A:$A,$A1),COUNTIF(Sheet3!$A:$A,$B1))
```

I have done this for 2 columns A and B only. Please do the same for all columns till K inside the OR condition. The Sheet 3 should contain the list of all 800 items in column A. Let me know if you need anything else

Comment: hmm.. if i use the formula you posted, i only get a true out of it. And its no compatible for multiple search values

Comment: you should be using this in conditional formatting - > new rule - > "use a formula to determine which cells to format".  Not in the cells in the excel

Comment: I know, but i cant make for every single word a formula in the rules

Comment: ya got it, have to find some other way for it. Will work out that

Comment: Well i got in use A-K, but A are the 5k Words